# Javascript/AngularJS: How do I make click event trigger parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

```
<div id="fb-button-container" style="width:20%; margin:auto;"  data-ng-show="!isLoggedIn" data-ng-click="checkFacebookLoginState()">
    <div class="fb-login-button"  data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false">Login with Facebook</div><!--data-ng-disabled="!facebookReady"-->
</div>
```

I have this code. I'm using Facebook Login plug-in.

The problem I got is that if I put **data-ng-click** straight on the **fb-login-button** click event is not triggered (probably because overriden by default Facebook's click event).

So I put it in the parent. But this way I have to click **outside** from the button to trigger it.

I was wondering: is there a way to forse **"backpropagation"** of click event from child (fb-login-button) to parent (fb-button-container)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to know if someone clicks? And no it is not possible

Comment: It doesn't make sense... you just said the FB button overrides ng-click... so then how would you "backpropogate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather silly approach would be using another element inside the parent, which will act as a main trigger. Inside the checkFacebookLoginState(), listen to the click event, and execute another click to the hidden fb login button when needed.

```html
<div id="fb-button-container" style="width:20%; margin:auto;"  data-ng-show="!isLoggedIn">
    <div class="fb-login-check" data-ng-click="checkFacebookLoginState()"></div>
    <div class="fb-login-button hidden"  data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false">Login with Facebook</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put a div the size and shape of the Facebook button in front of the it by giving it a higher z-index so they will be clicking on your div and not the Facebook button.

This is not really an answer to your question, but a solution to your problem.